# My Computer hacked?

Tags: windows, malware

I have Window 7 and believe it has been hacked. On two occasions, as I was reloading my operating system, I got a message that my computer had been counterfeited. I get the impression that my computer is booting up to a remote server somewhere. Occasionally I notice that some directories have a lock icon on it and I cannot either access or delete it. Security permissions are under strange names and I can't delete them. Is my only hope to format? Can my bios be hacked? Not sure what to do at this point. After running some registry scans on System Mechanic, I get an "Access violation at address 13B10ED2 in module 'SysMech.exe". Read of address 00000000.' every time I close the program. There are other suspicious things going on but these are some of the most obvious. I also get unusual font characters in my vertical scroll bar as well as when I login to my e-mail.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a license for Windows 7.  Have you activated your installation?  I would run a `sfc /scannow` it sounds like System Mechanic corrupted your Windows installation.  Sounds like you should just reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 3):

SystemMechanic appears to me to be not a very reliable program.

I would recommend ceasing any unnecessary activity on the affected computer, especially disconnecting it from the internet immediately, and performing a backup from a live-CD on another storage device.

The next thing to do would be to consult HijackThis or MalwareBytes AntiMalware as well as your (hopefully working) Antivirus Software.

Edit: Actually, given the state of your system, get https://www.botfrei.de/en/decleaner.html and put it on a CD. Boot from that CD (after you have a backup, of course!) and see what comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into safe mode and check the drives for errors, run a malware scan, spyware scan and then virus scan. If all this fails, try a system restore back to a known working point.

Difficult to comment further as the issue could lie anywhere...

Comment: Try Malwarebytes while you're at it.